# How to correctly add new line to the file when multiple lines are added in parallel?

Tags: linux

I have to fill file with thousands of new lines, which i do with a simple command:

```
echo line1 >> allLines &
echo line2 >> allLines &
echo line3 >> allLines &
echo line4 >> allLines &
```

With an output:

```
cat allLines
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

However, rarely but regularly error slips in, where new line is concatenated to an existing one, producing a following output:

```
cat allLines
line1
line2line3
line4
```

How to avoid such error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply put all files in one folder and stacked them without parallelisation